# How to override 'mapred.user.jobconf.limit' value in driver class?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have mapreduce job which requires more than current value of 10mb which is set in mapred-site.xml. I want to use temporarily increased value for my current job. Can I set it in the driver class, like 'job.setXXXXXX()' ? And also I dont want to use -D option at command line

Answer (score 0):

You can try use -D option at command line, and check the real result on the webUI that contains the job, in the .../job.xml. Like the picture :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont want to use -D option and after some research I found that mapred-user-jobconf-limit cannot be over-ridden at job level. It can only set at service wide jobtracker level.